# Make ulimits work with start-stop-daemon

Tags: debian, ulimit

I have an `init.d` script that starts an app using `start-stop-daemon --chuid SOME_SYSTEM_USER`. That is, the app runs under a different user, not root.

Problem is, the app needs special limit settings (namely `ulimit -n 64000`), which I set in `limits.conf`. This works quite nicely when I run it directly from shell: `su - SOME_SYSTEM_USER` + start app from shell.

But when run through the `start-stop-daemon --chuid` from `/etc/init.d`, these limits are ignored. Then the app fails to work, obviously.

How do I force `start-stop-daemon` to honour the `ulimit` settings?

---

Debian Squeeze, 2.6.32-5-686 #1 SMP Sat May 5 01:33:08 UTC 2012 i686 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 24, accepted):

At this time, you can't. `limits.conf(5)` is the configuration for `pam_limits(8)`, which is activated by the PAM stack according to the configuration in `/etc/pam.d`. However, `start-stop-daemon(8)` as launched from an init.d script doesn't pass through the PAM stack, so those kinds of settings are never applied.

Debian bug [#302079](https://bugs.debian.org/302079) contains a patch to enable setting limits from `start-stop-daemon(8)`, but the bug has been open since 2005 and the patch hasn't been merged yet.

While not ideal, AFAIK the recommended way to accomplish this right now is to add a `ulimit` call in your init.d script.

Comment: Just add the `ulimit` setting right before the `start-stop-daemon` command. (i.e `ulimit -n 64000`) ... for the ignorant like me.

Comment: If, unlike the OP, you don't know which daemon's crashing, I just got good results on Debian Wheezy restarting daemons after: echo "ulimit -c unlimited" | sudo tee /lib/lsb/init-functions.d/core-limit

Comment: Some more valuable background information can be found here: http://serverfault.com/a/642082/22394

Answer (score 7):

You can also use the 'limit' command in the upstart script.

In the file /etc/init/foo.conf, add the line:

```
limit nofile 64000 64000
```

The first 64000 is the soft limit, and the second is the hard limit.

You can find more information here:
http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/